# Laravel - ServiceProvider : Give me Error 500

Tags: php, laravel, provider

After using a ServiceProvider, Laravel give me an Error 500...
If I remove the :

I know, there's no need of binding because there's no DI, I am experiencing...

**GameController :**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Game;

use App;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class GameController extends Controller
{
    public function start(GameRepositoryInterface $gameRepository) {
        return $gameRepository->getLastAdd();
    }
}
```

**GameServiceProvider :**

```
namespace App\Providers\Game;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Http\Controllers\Game\StdGameRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\Game\GameRepositoryInterface;

class GameServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register() {
        dd('ici');
        $this->app->bind(StdGameRepository::class, function() {
           return new StdGameRepository();
        });

        $this->app->bind(GameRepositoryInterface::class, StdGameRepository::class);
    }

    public function provides() {
        return [GameRepositoryInterface::class];
    }
}
```

**GameRepositoryInterface :**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Game;

interface GameRepositoryInterface
{
    public function getLastAdd();
}
```

**StdGameRepository :**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Game;

class StdGameRepository implements GameRepositoryInterface
{
    private $lastAdd = "Testing";

    public function getLastAdd()
    {
        return $this->lastAdd;
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: I try to get more information but all i got is "GET http://localhost/~macbook/projects/laravel/start 500 (Internal Server Error)"...  I set env('APP_DEBUG', true) and modify the php.ini but I can't get more...

Comment: Check your log file. `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm on Laravel Framework 5.4.14, and the last thing in laravel.log is from [2017-03-04 18:20:24]...

Comment: It probably isn't the case at all but for the sake of it you could try changing `\App\...` to `App\...` in your providers array.

Comment: Thanks, I just change that, and the error now show up when i use the class which need the SP, any idea ? (I edit the post with the code of the controller using it)